# Problem with memory allocation 3d char array C

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to read a 2d array of values from a file and then trying to copy that to a 2d array of Strings in C. When I ran my code using gdb I got an error that said "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer" for the line where I "free( tmval )". Then when I ran the code using valgrind I get several "Invalid write size of 8" that happen whenever I try to read or write a string in the 2d array.

The problem happens during this portion of the code:

> ```
>   //allocate memory for transition matrix
>   tm = (char ***) malloc( numstates*NUM_CLASSES-1*4*sizeof( char ) );
>
>   //initialize variables needed for loop
>   int i = 0;
>   char *tmval = (char *) calloc( 4, sizeof( char ) );
>
>   // read and process all the remaining lines from the file
>   while( fgets(buf, MAXBUF, fp) != NULL ) {
>     //add comment detection
>     if( buf[0] !='#' ){
>       
>       //allocate transition states for each row using calloc
>       tm[i] = (char **) calloc( NUM_CLASSES-1, (4*sizeof( char )) );
>     
>       //strok first with space to skip row number
>       ptr = strtok( buf, " " );
>       
>       for( int j = 0;j<NUM_CLASSES-1;j++ ){
>         //allocate space for string in array
>         tm[i][j] = (char *) calloc( 4, sizeof( char ) );
>         tm[i][j] = "-1d";
>       }
>
>       //loop through line to get class numbers and corresponding states
>       ptr = strtok( NULL, " " );
>       while( ptr!=NULL ){
>         int cls = strtol( ptr, end, 10 );
>         tmval = *end+1;
>         tm[i][cls] = tmval;
>         ptr = strtok( NULL, " " );
>       }
>       
>       //iterate i
>       i++;
>     }
>   }
>
>   //free up tmval and file
>   fclose( fp );
>   free( tmval );
>   free( end );
> ```

I believe this maybe the root of the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it:

> ```
> tm[i] = (char **) calloc( NUM_CLASSES-1, (3*sizeof( char )) );
> ```

The input file for the program is formatted like this

> ```
> 0  0/0d  1/0d  2/1s  3/3s  4/2s  5/2s  6/5s  7/4s  8/4s  10/9d
> 1  0/9d  1/9d  2/1s  3/1s  4/1s  5/1s  10/9d
> ```

The first number is the row number and the number before the / column number for the value that comes after the /.

I think that many of the Valgrind errors are happening because my memory allocation sizes don't match, but I'm not sure how I can fix that because to me they look ok. Also what is causing the error when I try to free up the space for tmval.

Comment: Where are you making copies?  It looks like all of your pointers are into `buf`, which is getting overwritten on each iteration.

Comment: And the `free` s are indeed all invalid because you are trying to free memory that is in buf.  Instead of `tmval = *end+1;`, you need some sort of `memcpy` or `strcpy`.

Comment: What is `tm[i][j] = "-1d";` supposed to do?  It causes the memory allocated in the immediately-previous line to leak, and when you try to free `tm[i][j]` it will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The allocation size in `tm = (char ***)malloc( numstates*NUM_CLASSES-1*4*sizeof(char))` is bogus because

- `NUM_CLASSES-1` must be parenthesized.
- you compute the size of a 3D packed array but use types that are inconsistent with this: `char ***tm` has nothing to do with `char tm[numstates][NUM_CLASSES-1][4];`

Parsing the line of input is incorrect too:

- `tmval = *end+1;` makes `tmval` point inside the array `buf`, so the next statement `tm[i][cls] = tmval;` makes the entry in the pseudo-2D array point inside the `buf` array, which will be overwritten immediately upon reading the next line.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_CLASSES  20
#define MAXBUF  1024

// load_matrix allocates and returns a 3D matrix loaded with the transition states
char (*load_matrix(FILE *fp, int numstates))[NUM_CLASSES - 1][4] {
    char buf[MAXBUF];
    //allocate memory for transition matrix
    char (*tm)[NUM_CLASSES - 1][4] = calloc(sizeof(*tm), numstates);

    //initialize transition states for all rows
    for (int i = 0; i < numstates; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_CLASSES - 1; j++)
            strcpy(tm[i][j], "-1d");
    }
    // read and process all the remaining lines from the file
    while (fgets(buf, MAXBUF, fp) != NULL) {
        char *ptr, *end;

        //add comment detection
        if (buf[0] == '#')
            continue;

        //strok first with space to skip row number
        ptr = strtok(buf, " \t\n");
        if (!ptr)
            continue;

        int row = strtol(ptr, &end, 10);
        if (ptr == end || row < 0 || row >= numstates) {
            // invalid row
            continue;
        }

        //loop through line to get class numbers and corresponding states
        while ((ptr = strtok(NULL, " \t\n")) != NULL) {
            int cls = strtol(ptr, &end, 10);
            if (end > ptr && *end++ == '/' && strlen(end) < 4 && cls >= 0 && cls < NUM_CLASSES - 1)
                strcpy(tm[row][cls], end);
        }
    }
    return tm;
}
```

The matrix is allocated in a single call to `calloc()` and can be freed with `free(tm)`. Here is an example:

```
int main() {
    char (*tm)[NUM_CLASSES - 1][4] = load_matrix(stdin, 100);
    [...]
    free(tm);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the line `char *tmval = (char *) calloc( 4, sizeof( char ) );` , which allocates some memory and assigns its address to `tmval`.  You later have the line `tmval = *end+1;` which reassigns `tmval` the address of some memory that is in `buf`.  Reassigning the value discards your only copy of the address of the memory that the `calloc` allocated, and is effectively a memory leak.   The subsequent `free(tmval)` is invalid, because the memory that `tmval` now addresses was not created by `calloc`, but is inside `buf`.

Assigning to a pointer does not copy memory.  You need `memcpy` or `strcpy` (or something similar) to make a copy of the data.